# Configuration with name 'default' not found - React Native

Tags: android, react-native

When I run `react-native run-android` I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
   > Configuration with name 'default' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I know that this means that there is some linking error, but I cannot figure out what. I would love some help with the fix, I am very new to android.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This happens when `build.gradle` is not found for one of your package dependencies.

To debug this issue, inside your react native project run

```
cd android
./gradlew clean --info
```

After running this command, you can see where the building stops. Go to that package github page and search in issues. You will most probably find the answer. In my case it was because of `react-native-maps`, so I have to modify `settings.gradle` to point the real location of `build.gradle` for that package

Comment: This was super helpful thank you! What happened for me was `react-native unlink` did not completely uninstall a package. It had left a line in `MainApplication.java`. I had already uninstall the npm package, so it was trying to find something in a directory that didn't exist. So I just had to manually remove the lines from `MainApplication.java`.

Comment: The problem when using react native is you can get started but are likely very ignorant of how native builds work. Thanks for helping us understand things by giving a reason, not just some fix.

Comment: This saved me. Thanks @reku.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue happens to me also in case of using

> react-native-sms-android

my solution:

> npm install react-native-sms-android  --save

and then modifiying the rest files as described in documentation.